# JQuery slideup and slidedown is not smooth enough

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I am implementing a slide dropdown and i am using this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.drop').click(function(){
        var $next = $(this).parent().next('li.drop_down');
        if($next.is(':visible')) {
            $next.slideUp();
        } else {
            $next.slideDown();
        }
    });
});
```

but the client claims that it is not smooth enough. He wants to expand really smooth, so is there a way to make it smoother

Comment: Matt - You should show your appreciation for those who take the time out of their day to help you and "Accept" helpful answers by clicking the checkmark next to the answer.

Comment: I did not have smooth slide up and down until i gave min-height for my slided div... As you did not show us the css, if you have min-height, try it without.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might want to incorporate the [easing plugin](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/) for smoother animation.

Comment: How would i use the easing plugin in my situation. I know i have to add the source but do i change the slideup and down to account for it

Answer (score 4):

If your animation is not smooth you need to give the element that gets slidedUp/slidedDown a width in pixel (not in percent!), this helps me most of the time.

Answer (score 3):

I just came across your question and I have the same problem. For men what fixed it is to remove padding. I don't know but for some reason it is not taken into account as a total of the element's height.

Answer (score 2):

according to all answers and my experience:

1. don't use min-height.
2. don't use padding (set padding for inside of
   container is ok).
3. don't use width in percent.

p.s. 1: you can use responsive width (in percent), but you have remove padding (set internal container element padding).

p.s. 2: you can use fixed width and padding together, sometimes its work properly.

Answer (score 1):

You  could try the [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) library.  The Event() class provides a Slide effect where you can adjust speed and other presentation-related attributes

http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/

Answer (score 1):

You can incrase the animation duration by adding a number of ms inside the slideUp/slideDown()'s:

```
    if($next.is(':visible')) {
        $next.slideUp(2500);
    } else {
        $next.slideDown(2500);
    }
```

That should get all the smoothness you need.